# PHP Browser Conditional

Tags: php, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-9, conditional-statements

What I am trying to do is making a PHP Conditional specifically for IE9. What I've tried so far are these two PHP Browser Conditionals

```
if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [9]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) 
{ 
   //my code here 
   exit; 
}

if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false) 
{
   //my code here 
}
```

Did I write them incorrectly? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'd use conditional comments instead. Must admit though that I've never needed specific code for our 9.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you are trying to target ie9 specifically?  There may be an alternate solution.

Comment: Or you could just use [get_browser()](http://php.net/get_browser)

Comment: I am targeting IE9 specially to fix some borders that was coded within a PHP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 9.') !== false) { 
  //my code here 
   exit; 
}
```

Comment: Judging by the comments on that manual page - not all that capable.

Answer (score 0):

You should not filter browsers for any reason. Instead, use feature detection to see if the browser is capable of what you are trying to do.

Aside from that, the User-Agent string is unreliable and can literally be set to anything, or even not sent at all.